# Java MySQL UPDATE error using WHERE in conjunction with AND

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to `UPDATE` an entry in MySQL, the structure of the table is `table_rankings (ip text, field text, rank double)`. Where `ip` is a user's IP address, `field` is an object being ranked and `rank` is the numerical rank of a field. My statement is:

```
//String for query
String query = "UPDATE "+catagory+"_rankings SET rank = ? WHERE ip = ? AND field = ? )";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
//fill ? variables
ps.setDouble(1, r[i]);
ps.setString(2, user);
ps.setString(3, s[i]);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

In this code `catagory` refers to a given table, for instance `baseball_rankings` or `basketball_rankings`. The error I am receiving is:

```
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
SQLState: 42000
VendorError: 1064
```

Is the issue that I cannot use `WHERE` as well as `AND` in an `UPDATE` statement? I am also curious if my update is subject to a SQL injection attack because I am using `catagory+"_rankings"`. I have tried to use a `?` variable however it results in another error.

Comment: you have only a closing parentheses

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think he can.  Not for the table name.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Why not (I'm curious)?

Comment: That seems to be correct, when I replace the concatenation with the prepared statement I get an error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You'd have to ask the designers of JDBC why you can't use a parameter for the table name.  I don't know.  I'm just fairly sure it doesn't work.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Then I retract my comment.  I was just afraid that somehow the OP could be SQL injected by concatenating the table name like this.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem it does not, here is the error if you are interested `SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''cast_rankings' SET rank = 13.0 WHERE ip = '19' AND field = 'hi'' at line 1
SQLState: 42000
VendorError: 1064`

Comment: Sure, it's a vulnerability.  One must be careful to sanitise one's input when doing this kind of thing. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Is there a better way aside from writing a different method for each field?

Comment: Why would you write a different method for each field?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I meant table, not field, I will update that.

Comment: If you have a bunch of tables all with similar structures, then is there a good reason not to change your database structure to just have a single table?

Comment: They all have a similar structure, however, the data is fairly unrelated. But baring some sort of encapsulation not really, I could simply add a field that contains a classifier like `basketball` or `baseball`.

Comment: You don't combine tables because they​ have a "similar structure". That's not data engineering. The data model flows from the domain analysis through various normalizations. Without knowing the actual table structures and what they model, it's impossible to know if they should be combined. If the modeling was done competently​ then it would be unlikely.

Comment: It's advisable to spell the natural-language parts of identifiers​ conventionally. As a habit it supports code maintainability​.

Comment: If anything is mis-spelled it is purely because I am terrible at spelling.

Comment: @LewBloch what was spelled incorrectly?

Comment: `catagory` for "category"

Comment: Thanks! I'll fix that!

Comment: @LewBloch They all seem to be rankings of some kind, but I don't know what the categories are.  They all look to be updated in the same general way.  It might well be appropriate to model them in a single table, with a column for the category.

Comment: They are all related to movie cast, production team, writer, director, etc. I don't really know why I listed sports before, the table holds a user's rankings for each person.

Comment: Is there a good thread or book to read for this, I have no formal education in SQL or any sort of data engineering.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find loads of good resources on data analysis and/or data modelling.  I'm afraid it's about 20 years since I was formally teaching this stuff, so I'm no longer aware of what's out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you add a extra “)”， or can say, you missed a "(".

try

```
String query = "UPDATE "+catagory+"_rankings SET rank = ? WHERE ip = ? AND field = ? ";
```

Comment: That is infuriating, I have been looking at this code for hours.